# PC shutting down instantly process.start("shutdown", " /s /t")

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, shutdown, system-shutdown

I want to shut the PC after the time I set is over *(For the input I used 3 TextBoxes)*, but when I press the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totalSeconds = int.Parse(hours.Text.ToString()) * 120 +
                       int.Parse(minutes.Text.ToString()) * 60 + 
                       int.Parse(seconds.Text.ToString());

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t " + totalSeconds.ToString());
}
```

The PC shuts down instantly.

**Edit: The code above wasn't the problem, it works just fine, the problem was, that i had `InitialiseComponent();` two times in the `Form1()`  function.**

Comment: You could use a debugger to see what value `totalSeconds` actually holds.

Comment: You realize an hour is 60 times larger than a minute, not 2, right? So you should be multiplying hours by 3600, not 120.

Comment: `Hour = 60 (min) * 60 (sec)` and not 120.

Comment: All 4 `.ToString()` calls are redundant and could/should be removed.

Comment: @itsme86 haha yeah oops, but still it shouldnt shutdown instantly

Comment: @UweKeim I tried that and now I now I found out that my problem is that all the text in the _TextBoxes_ stays "00" (what I put into the _Text_ attribute of the Textbox) and doesn't change to what I type in.

Comment: @Gaweringo did you try my code. please response for the answer

Comment: @Sachith yes I tried it, and I found out, that my problem isn't the Button click Code, but the fact that the Text from my Textboxes doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, here I'm hard coded hour,minute and shutdown values, you can set those values by using textboxes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 string shutdown = "-s"; // -s -> shutdown
 int hour = 1 * 60 * 60; //3600 seconds
 int minute = 1 * 60; //60 seconds
 int second = 1; //1 seconds
 int totalSeconds = hour + minute + second; //total seconds should be : 3661
 Process.Start("Shutdown", shutdown + " -t " + totalSeconds + @" -c ""Windows is going to shutdown!"""); // -t = time , -c = comments

}
```

In addition, if you want abort shutdown you can use this code line, `Process.Start("Shutdown", "-a");`